# Get Store Code from Shipment Tracking

Tags: php, magento

I am in the sales/order/shipment/view/tracking template and need to print a different tracking link based on which store the order was placed in. Admittedly, I'm fairly new to Magento so this may be really obvious, but I'm not sure how to get the store id from here. I've tried:

```
$store = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
```

which only pulls up the store that I'm currently viewing the template in (so 0 as I'm in admin).

I also tried:

```
$store = $this -> getShipment()->getParam('store_id');
```

but that doesn't seem to do anything.

How should I go about finding the store code or id while in the tracking template?